# How to display fetched data in functional react-redux component?

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit

Why I see always "loading..."?
I used redux-toolkit and createSlice and fetch data by axios.
I have not any problem by fetching data and my data is in State.
My problem is displaying fetched data.
My Component code is:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';    
import {fetchTrackers} from 'dashboard/dashboardSlice';    
export default function TrackerManagerDashboard() {
    const [trackersList, setTrackersList] = useState(useSelector(state => state.trackersData));
    const [activeTracker, setActiveTracker] = useState(useSelector(state => state.activeTracker));
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchTrackers);
    }, []);
   if(!trackersList)
        return (
            <div>loading...</div>
        )
    return (
        <div className="TrackerManagerDashboard">
            ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

and reducer Slice file is:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import * as env from "../../environments";
import axios from 'axios';    
const initialState = {
    trackersData: {},
    activeTracker: {},
}   
const dashboardSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'dashboard',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setInitialState(state, action) {
            state.trackersData = action.payload.data;
            state.activeTracker = state.trackersData[Object.keys(state.trackersData)[0]];
        },
    },
})    
export async function fetchTrackers (dispatch, getState) {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(env.APP_URL + '/fetch/trackers.json');
        dispatch(setInitialState({type: 'setInitialState', data }));
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}    
export const { setInitialState} = dashboardSlice.actions
export default dashboardSlice.reducer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use `useState(useSelector`.

That means "create a component-local state with the initial value that the return value of `useSelector` at the time of first render has". If the Redux state changes later, you will never get to see it, as your `useState` is already initialized and any change there will not be reflected in your `trackersList` variable.

Instead, just call `useSelector`:

```js
const trackersList = useSelector(state => state.trackersData);
const setActiveTracker = useSelector(state => state.activeTracker);
```

Comment: With your help, I was able to access the state. Unfortunately, only the initial state value is returned and the fetched values inside it are not stored in the variables.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally submitted without adjusting your example correctly. I removed the `useState` from them, as it should be. Is it working now?